# Expanding Custom TableviewCell not working properly and displays incorrect view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a table view controller with a section cell and on click it expands and other subsections are showed. A section cell will always have title and a button and it may or may not have a description, on expanding the cell with no description, I am applying a centerYanchor on the title of the section cell so that it's aligned accordingly to the expand icon.

On expanding the cells which have a  description it works as expected, also the section with no description has centerYanchor applied to it and works properly.

Now the problem that I am facing is as soon as I expand a cell with no description, the cells with description starts to behave weirdly on expanding.

[image]

As you can see the first two cells with description opened properly and other cells with no description is also aligned with the button.

[image]

In this case I opened the third cell first and on opening the first cell, even though it had description the centerYanchor and hiden logic is being applied to it.

Here is the code for tableViewController

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableData[section].opened == true{
        return tableData[section].sectionData.count + 1
    } else{
        return 1
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "anotherCell", for: indexPath) as? tableCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell has thrown some error.")
        }
        cell.cellTitle.text = tableData[indexPath.section].title
        cell.cellDescription.text = tableData[indexPath.section].description
        cell.setData = tableData[indexPath.section].opened
        return cell
    } else{
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "subSectionCell", for: indexPath) as? subSectionTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell has thrown some error.")
        }
        cell.subSectionTitle.text = tableData[indexPath.section].sectionData[indexPath.row - 1]
        return cell
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        if tableData[indexPath.section].opened == true {
            tableData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }
        else{
            tableData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for hiding and applying the centerYanchor to the cell

```
var setData: Bool = false {
    didSet{
        setupCell()
    }
}


func setupCell() {
    if (cellDescription.text == "") {
        cellDescription.isHidden = true
        cellTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    }

    if setData{
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "down"), for: .normal)
    } else{
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "right"), for: .normal)

    }

}
```

Please suggest me on how I should fix this, and if you have any doubts ask in the comments.

Cell Data Struct

```
struct cData {
    var title = String()
    var description = String()
    var identifier = Int()
    var opened = Bool()
    var sectionData = [String]()

}
```

Cells constraints

[image]

Comment: I think you need to provide a little more information... Can you show your cell prototype with constraints? Can you also show your data structure with sample data?

Comment: please have a look

Comment: ok... so, if the cell HAS a description, you want the arrow image centerY equal to the descriptionLabel centerY, and if it has NO description, equal to the titleLabel centerY?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: you have a couple issues going on, related to cell reuse... First, you are setting the description label to hidden if it has no text, but you're not setting it back to un-hidden if when it *does* have text. Second, you cannot keep adding constraints. Third, I don't see from you layout how you are determining the row height based on the description label being hidden or not. Take a look at this image: https://imgur.com/a/6YyhnpT (the colors just make it easy to see the frames). Is that how you want it to look?

Comment: else {
            cellDescription.isHidden = false
            cellTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = false
        } 
I added the else too, but this did not help me. Yeah you are right, I have set the constraints on titleLabel and Description but there is not constraint for their heights and also I want it to look as it is there in your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggested layout.

Yellow is the cell's `contentView`; orange is the `View` the contains the other elements; labels have cyan background.

[image]

Embed the labels in a `UIStackView`:

[image]

Give the "arrow button" a `centerY` constraint to the Description label, with `Priority: 751` ***AND*** give it a `centerY` constraint to the Title label, with `Priority: 750`. That will automatically center it on the Description label when it is visible, and on the Title label when Description is hidden.

Then change your cell's `setupCell()` func as follows:

```
func setupCell() {

    // set all subviews background colors to white
    //[contentView, view, cellTitle, cellDescription, button].forEach {
    //  $0?.backgroundColor = .white
    //}

    // hide if no text, otherwise show
    cellDescription.isHidden = (cellDescription.text == "")

    if setData{
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "down"), for: .normal)
    } else{
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "right"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

During dev, I like to use contrasting colors to make it easy to see the layout. If you un-comment the `.forEach` block, everything will get a white background. After I have my layout correct, I go back to Storyboard and set the background colors to white (or clear, or however I *really* want them) and remove the color setting from the code.

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked, I was stuck on it from yesterday. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cell reuse issue here:

```
if (cellDescription.text == "") {
        cellDescription.isHidden = true
        cellTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
    }
```

Your cells are being reused, but you're never actually showing the cellDescription if it's available:

```
if (cellDescription.text == "") {
            cellDescription.isHidden = true
            cellTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        } else {
            cellDescription.isHidden = false
            cellTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.centerYAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = false
        }
```

Comment: Try adding layoutSubviews command after editing cell constraints, that one might be needed as well.